# What would a long-term self-study track look like for functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning

For context, I have a graduate level computer science background and after doing some research on agent-based modeling and systems science I am convinced there is potential to formalize emergence and evolution into its own theoretical discipline which can be a foundation for unified science -- bridging theoretical 'STEM' and practical 'non-STEM' schools.

At the end I want to go into an academic or research program doing exactly that but that might be at least some years for personal reasons. I am also concerned getting into a formal academic program without the background to pick who to be taught by might end up stunting me. A lot of the work in the field is downright esoteric and my fear is doing research and getting mentored too deep in the wrong rabbit hole can make it impossible to formulate anything with interdisciplinary value.

So I want to do some self-guided studying for the time being (2-4 years) to attain the kind of background in functional analysis that can help me formulate my own concepts, or at the very least know how to find and understand research others publish for what I mentioned above. What are some ways I can go about that after brushing up on real and complex analysis?

Comment: How do "emergence and evolution" have anything to do with _functional analysis_? (Are you aware of what functional analysis actually _is_? It's not analyzing how things function - it's a specific area of math, namely the study of topological vector spaces.)

Comment: This is why I am asking this question. I want to be able to express concepts like emergence in terms of functions defined in a vector space and conflate evolution with convergence, for instance. I want to set a plan to learn the terminology, identify the people working on the matter, read and understand papers etc.

"How do "emergence and evolution" have anything to do with functional analysis" is what I am hoping to be able to answer when I get to the level of being able to produce research

Comment: Whatever - the idea that that's going to havve anything to do with functional analysis seems very implausible - nothing in either version of your comment seems to me to indicate otherwise. Anyway, to answer your question about how to learn functional analysis: Get a book on the topic and read it. Rudin "Functional Analysis" for example.

Comment: "I want to set a plan to [...] identify the people working on the matter": Do you have any reason to believe that there _are_ people studying emergence and evolution via functional analysis?

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm certain there's a lot of math that has a lot to do with emergence and evolution, I just can't imagine how functional analysis could be relevant. After all, my impression is that "mathematical theory of evolution" is more or less a recognized discipline. Seems to me you'd be better off learning about what people in the field have actually done, instead of deciding in advance it's going to involve functional analysis.

Comment: I will assume your questions are well intended despite the inflammatory tone. It is used to explain quantum mechanical systems so I don't see why it would be implausible to use the same tools for higher level abstract systems. As for whether if there are those people, in a way. A lot of real analysis concepts appear in probability theory under completely different terminology for instance. And again, I have good reason to believe that it can be a useful tool for explaining systems emergence from an abstract view, why would it not be?

Comment: Say if you look into cellular automata they act in a certain 'meta-pattern'. Can one go about formulating an abstract cellular automata system in terms of a vector space? That's what I want to be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn functional analysis you need to find a book on the subject and read it. Rudin *Functional Analysis*, for example. Hmm, maybe first you should study something  like the chapters on Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces in for example Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* or Folland *Real Analysis*.

(Yes, that seems like a pretty lame answer, being sort of obvious/trivial. But it *is* the answer. What other sort of answer might you expect?)

Comment: Anything significant to supplement or cross reference? Like looking into topology could be useful beforehand or cross referencing applications in physics can help with intuition, anything besides?